# Loop array value into object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i have problem with my javascript project.
i have an array with value like this :

```
exmpArr = ["PX1","PX2","PX3"];
```

and i want to loop and push it to obj like this:

```
sections = [
            {
             rows: [
              { title: exmpArr[i], rowId: exmpArr[i] },
              ],
            },
           ];
```

the final value must like this:

```
sections = [
            {
             rows: [
              { title: "PX1", rowId: "PX1" },
              { title: "PX2", rowId: "PX2" },
              { title: "PX3", rowId: "PX3" },
              ],
            },
           ];
```

what should i do?

what i did is i put for loop inside the object and its not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a *new* array from the one you're mapping over. So you can immediately assign that array as the property value when you build your object.

```js
const exmpArr = ['PX1', 'PX2', 'PX3'];

const sections = [
  {
    rows: exmpArr.map(el => {
      return { title: el, rowId: el };
    })
  }
];

console.log(sections);
```